# Python (If, Then) with DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with months (by year), and ID number. I am trying to calculate the attrition rate, but I am getting stuck on obtaining unique ID counts when a month equals a certain month in pandas.

| ID. | Month |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Sept. 2022 |
| 2 | Oct. 2022 |

etc... with possible duplicates in ID and 1.75 years worth of data.

```
import pandas as pd 

path = some path on my computer 
data = pd.read_excel(path)

if data["Month"] == "Sept. 2022":
   ID_SEPT = data["ID."].unique()
return ID_SEPT
```

I am trying to discover what I am doing incorrect here in this if-then statement. Ideally I am trying to collect all the unique ID values per each month per year to then calculate the attrition rate. Is there something obvious I am doing wrong here?

Thank you.

I tried an id-then statement and I was expecting unique value counts of ID per month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for pandas.groupby.

Use it like this to get the unique values of each Group (Month)

```
data.groupby("Month")["ID."].unique()  # You have a . after ID in your example, check if thats correct
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use one of the iterator functions, like [items()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.items.html).

```
for (columnName, columnData) in data.iteritems():
    if columnName = 'Month'
         [code]
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you do this with a dataframe, conceptually, is to filter the entire dataframe to be just the rows where your comparison is true, and then do whatever (get uniques) from there.

That would look like this:

```py
filtered_df = df[df['Month'] == 'Sept. 2022']
ids_sept = list(filtered_df['ID.'].unique()
```

The first line there can look at a little strange, but what it is doing is:

1. `df['Month'] == 'Sept. 2022'` will return an array/column/series (it actually returns a series) of `True/False` whether or not the comparison is, well, true or false.
2. You then run that series of bools through `df[series_of_bools]` that filters the dataframe to return only the rows where it is True.

Thus, you have a filter.

If you are looking for the number of unique items, rather than the list of unique items, you can also use `filtered_df['ID.'].nunique()` and save yourself the step later of getting the length of the list.

Comment: thank you for the comment, I leaned a lot reading through this response.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```py
data[data.Month=='Sept. 2022']['ID.'].unique()
```